# How should I the Residue Theorem to evaluate the integral $\int_{|z|=2} \frac{dz}{(z − 4)(z^3 − 1)}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, residue-calculus

How should I use the Residue Theorem to evaluate the integral

> $$ \int_{|z|=2}\frac{dz}{(z − 4)(z^3 − 1)}?$$

Comment: What have you done so far?  Have you computed the appropriate residues?  Showing us what you attempted will give us a better idea of how to help you.

Comment: The integrand has 4 poles, 3 inside and 1 outside the contour. the easiest way to compute the integral is deform the contour to infinity and pick up the negative of the residue of the pole at 4 instead of summing residues from 3 poles inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\int_{|z|=2}\frac{1}{(z-4)(z^3-1)}\,dz=2i\pi\text{Res}\left(\frac{1}{(z-4)(z^3-1)},1\right)=\frac{2i\pi}{3(1-4)}=-\frac{2\pi i}{9}.
$$